# Can encryption be disabled for the login handshake in SQL Server 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, encryption

When a client Application connects to SQL Server the login credentials are sent over the network in a TLS Encrypted Handshake Message.

For testing purposes I would like to have the login credentials sent in clear text. The password would still be hashed which is fine, but my network admin wants to be able to pick up the other login details in a trace file.

I’ve been told that there is some way to disable the encryption for the connection handshake in some cases for some applications, but I don’t have any details about how to do this or when it can be applied.

Comment: From what I understand so far:

SQL 2000 - Credentials could be encrypted, but may not always be if encryption is not enabled.

SQL 2005/8 - Credentials are guaranteed to be encrypted. A verified certificate will be used if available, if not then a self signed certificate will be generated.